# unix DATE command converts wrong in specific years

Tags: linux, date, ubuntu

The command

```
mydate=$(date -d "90 days 19850101" +%Y%m%d%H%M%S)
```

yields 19850401000000. But:

```
mydate=$(date -d "90 days 19830101" +%Y%m%d%H%M%S)
```

yields 19830401010000.

How is it possible that in year 1983 one hour is added on 1 April (which is a result I don't want), while for the year 1985 the answer is correct?

Comment: What timezone is it? Does it have daylight savings/summer time?

Comment: It is timezone UTC+3 in summer and UTC+2 in winter (Estonia), so daylight saving is on. However, i'm not sure if there was daylight saving in the 1980's.

Comment: http://www.timeanddate.com/worldclock/timezone.html?n=242&syear=1980 - dst switch changed from april to march

Comment: Thanks, this is the correct answer i belive by Mat. Good!